# Why do my filters work separately from each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two selections that are supposed to filter data, they work but separately, how do I make them filter data together?

When I click on the second select, it resets the data from the first one.  They filter the same data array, so the result is new all the time, I don't understand how to filter an already filtered array

How do I make a joint filter?

```
 //filter data
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState<ICompanie[]>(companiesData);

  // status filter
  const handleStatusFilter = (status: string): void => {
    const filterData = companiesData.filter((item) => {
      if (item.status === status) {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setAllData(filterData);
  };

  // category filter
  const handleCategoriesFilter = (category: string): void => {
    const filterData = companiesData.filter((item) => {
      if (item.category === category) {
        return item;
      }
    });

    setAllData(filterData);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe You need to maintain the already selected filter value in the state variable.
Please prefer the below code:

```
const [allData, setAllData] = useState<ICompanie[]>(companiesData);
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
    
                     //name = status/category
                     //value = actual value of filter
const handleFilter = (name:string, value:string) => {
      const filtersCopy = {...filters};
      filtersCopy[name] = value;

      const filtersKey = Object.keys(filtersCopy).filter((value)=>!!filtersCopy[value]);
        
      const filterData = companiesData.filter((item) => {
                  const filterCheck = []
                  filtersKey.forEach((value) => {
                    if(item[value] === filtersCopy[value]) {
                      filtercheck.push(value);
                    }
                  })
                  return filterCheck.length === filtersKey.length
       });

     setFilters(filtersCopy)
     setAllData(filterData);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but the data is not returned, after several filters there is no data in the array at all, so I do not understand how to make this filter

Comment: @DmitryStaver do you want to apply the filter for multiple statuses and multiple Categories or at a time there will be one status and one category?

Comment: I want to do like this: https://codepen.io/rrondon-perficient/pen/jOPdZZB

Comment: @DmitryStaver I have updated the above solution please try that.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `allData` is const and when you invoke `setAllData` you always apply the filter from the immutable `allData`, and lose update.
See if you want to expose `filterData` instead (e.g. turn `allData` to non const and assign `filterData` to it when you filter, maybe have a mechanism to restore the unfiltered original `allData`).